# Methods to fix redundancy

Tags: java, methods, redundancy

I have these few methods that use arrays and as you can see a lot of the code is repeated the only real differences are the primitive types change for each one. I was trying to figure out a method I could make that holds this repeated code but was unsuccessful.

```
public class Stat {

// Private double array data

private double data[];

// Default constructor that creates a double array having a single element of 0.0

public Stat() {

    data = new double[1];

    data[0] = 0.0;

} // End of method

/*
 * Constructs a Stat object of type double using the values held in d. The constructor
 * then creates a double array of the same length as d and holds copies of the values of d. A
 * reference to this new array is assigned to data. 
 */

public Stat(double[] d) {

    if (d == null) {

        for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {

            data[c] = 0;

        } // End of for loop

    } // End of if condition

    else {

        data = new double[d.length];

        for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {

            data[c] = d[c];

        } // End of for loop

    } // End of else statement

} // End of method

/*
 * Constructs a Stat object of type float using the values held in f. The constructor
 * then creates a double array of the same length as f and holds copies of the values of f. A
 * reference to this new array is assigned to data.
 */

public Stat(float[] f) {

    if (f == null) {

        for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {

            data[c] = 0;

        } // End of for loop

    } // End of if condition

    else {

        float[] data = new float[f.length];

        for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {

            data[c] = (float) f[c];

        } // End of for loop

    } // End of else condition

} // End of method

/*
 * Constructs a Stat object of type int using the values held in c. The constructor
 * then creates a double array of the same length as c and holds copies of the values of c. A
 * reference to this new array is assigned to data.
 */

public Stat(int[] i) {

    if (i == null) {

        for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {

            data[c] = 0;

        } // End of for loop

    } // End of if condition

    else {

        int[] data = new int[i.length];

        for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {

            data[c] = (int) i[c];

        } // End of for loop

    } // End of else condition

} // End of method

/*
 * Constructs a Stat object of type long using the values held in lo. The constructor
 * then creates a double array of the same length as lo and holds copies of the values of lo. A
 * reference to this new array is assigned to data.
 */

public Stat(long[] lo) {

    if (lo == null) {

        for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {

            data[c] = 0;

        } // End of for loop

    } //End of if condition

    else {

        long[] data = new long[lo.length];

        for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {

            data[c] = (long) lo[c];

        } // End of for loop

    } //End of else condition

} // End of method
```

Comment: Why are you accepting different types of arrays? My first inclination is to only accept `double[]`. If the user has some other type of array then they can convert it to `double[]` themselves, no need for this class to do it.

Comment: @JohnKugelman  This is like a specific part of one of my labs for computer science class and my professor wants it done this way for some reason and I have no clue why. I can post the code before it if that will help as well

Comment: I agree, only accepting double makes more sense if you're just going to cast the elements to double anyway.

In any case, you could use Arrays.fill(myArray, 0) to fill the arrays with zero instead of doing a for loop.

Comment: @dustinroepsch so there would be no methods that could be made to reduce the redundancies because the methods accepts different types?

Comment: Unfortunately when using primitive arrays, this is the sort of mess you end up with. It doesn't help that primitives and generics don't mix in Java.

Comment: @Slaw Darn! thank you though!

Comment: incidentally, primitive arrays are initialised to zero (or false)

Comment: To ensure I understand, is all you're trying to do is copy the input into a `double[]` field (i.e. `Stat.data`) where the input type can be any type of primitive array? Note your current code does not do this.

Answer (score 0):

This gets rid of some of the boilerplate.

But you would want to check the performance for large arrays. This does a lot of boxing/unboxing which might all get optimised away, or might not.

```
class Stat {
    private final double[] data;

    public Stat() {
        data = new double[1];
    }

     public Stat(int[] iData) {
         if (iData != null) {
             data = copy(iData.length, i -> (double)iData[i]);
         } else {
             data = new double[1];
         }
     }

     public Stat(float[] fData) {
         if (iData != null) {
             data = copy(iData.length, i -> (double)fData[i]);
         } else {
             data = new double[1];
         }
     }

     private double[] copy(int length, Function<Integer,Double> access) {
        double[] data = new double[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            data[i] = access.apply(i);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an [`IntToDoubleFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntToDoubleFunction.html) if you want to avoid auto(un)boxing.

Comment: You could also cut down on some code duplication by having `copy` return the `new double[1]` if you pass e.g. `-1` for the length. So you'd do `data = copy(data == null ? -1 : data.length)`. You could even move the `data == null ? -1 : data.length` to its own method.